# Where does cl compiler (visual studio) generates LIB and EXP files

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I used the following command in cl compiler that comes with Visual Studio.

```
cl /LD /O2 myprogram.c
```

and it said:

```
/out:myprogram.dll
/dll
/implib:myprogram.lib
myprogram.obj
    Creating library myprogram.lib and object myprogram.exp
```

My question is where did it output these files? They are not present in folder where my myprogram.c resides.

Comment: You probably forgot to export the functions that should be usable by other programs.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports to double-check.  Use __declspec(dllexport) or a .def file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. They are in folder c:\Windows\SysWOW64